# Jquery reposition element

Tags: jquery

I am repositioning html elements within same parent with this function:

```
function insertAtIndex(i, elem) {
    if(i == 0){
        selector.prepend(elem);        
    }else{
        selector.children().eq(i-1).after(elem);
    }
}
```

prepend works as intended, but after does nothing.

Is this because after does not remove the element before inserting it while prepend does?

If so, how do I use after in this case?

Comment: Do you mean 'append'? that's the inverse of 'prepend'. 'after' exists, but places content after the dom node instead of at the end of it. If not, can you make a codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: No, I mean after. These are all same level children which get repositioned. So reposition child with index 5 to index 3 etc...

Comment: okay -- can you make a codepen or jsfiddle or something?